# Multiple Testing Problem

Tags: regression

This is probably quite a elementary question. In the context of factor modelling/backtesting for investments, if there are multiple factors to regress (i.e. multiple null hypothesis), we run into the problem of multiple testing from my understanding, and you can adjust for the level of significance for correction.

But what about using multiple sample subsets to test for the same null hypothesis? e.g. test Fund manager A's relationship with equity beta factor, test fund manager B's relationship with the same equity beta. Do you still run into the problem of multiple comparison? I would of thought so, since you are still subject to increase in type I error the more test you carry out using a different sample subset each time. Is my understanding correct? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

Your understanding is spot on. The basic idea behind Type I errors is that we reject the null hypothesis when it would only occur in 5% (when alpha = .05) of cases *if the null hypothesis is true* (because that data would be pretty unlikely in that scenario). The consequence is that there is a 5% chance to reject the null hypothesis when it is true. So statistically, if you run *k* tests, your [family-wise error](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Familywise_error_rate) always grows by *k* * 5%. Mathematically, this is always true.

*However*, theoretically some would argue otherwise. If you find the same (significant) effect in different subsamples, your confidence of the effect existing would grow. The problem with this reasoning is that it is intuitive and overlooks the chance of the effect being spurious due to the innate problems of family-wise error, that occurs with null hypothesis testing.